# Why SQL statement doesn't work? How do transactions work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

**Question expression:**

I am trying out a few things with regards to transactions.  Consider the following operations:

1. Open a connection window 1 in SQL Server Management Studio
2. `BEGIN` a transaction, then delete about 2000 rows of data from table A
3. Open another connection window 2 in SQL Server Management Studio
4. Insert one new row of data into table A in window 2 (no transaction), it runs successfully right now

Then, I repeat the same operation, but in STEP 2 I delete 10k rows of data, in that case, STEP 4 can't run successfully. I had already waited for half an hour.

It shows that it is executing SQL...can't finish.  Finally, I insert the data using connection window 1, it works right now.

Why does it work with 2k rows but not 10k rows?

---

**The Sql sentence I execute:**

In connection windows A, I execute
  BEGIN TRAN
  Delete from tableA (10K rows)

In connection windows B, I execute
   Insert into tableA(..) VALUES (...)

windows B can't executes successfully.

---

Many thanks @Gordon

**The cause**:

I search the keyword about lock escalation.
I try to track lock escalation using SQL Server Profiler, and I get a
lock:escalation when I delete many data in a transaction(I don't commit or rollback).

So, I know the concept of lock escalation.
I delete too much data in a table ,then the row locks escalation to table escalation.I didn't commit or rollback them, other connection (or application)
can't access the table with table lock.
[trace lock escalation in sql profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNd6A.png)

---

**When the lock escalation happens in MSSQL Server**

"The locks option also affects when lock escalation occurs. When locks is set to 0, lock escalation occurs when the memory used by the current lock structures reaches 40 percent of the Database Engine memory pool. When locks is not set to 0, lock escalation occurs when the number of locks reaches 40 percent of the value specified for locks."

---

**How to set Using SQL Server Management Studio that will impact lock escalation:**

To configure the locks option
In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties .

Click the Advanced node.

Under Parallelism , type the desired value for the locks option.

Use the locks option to set the maximum number of available locks, such limiting the amount of memory SQL Server uses for them.

Comment: Did you `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` the transaction? Did you `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`? Are you using `TABLE Hints`?

Comment: @Sami No, I did't .

Comment: It's usually a good idea to paste the code you are using rather than outlining the process. Often, what someone says they are doing and what their code actually does are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are experiencing is "lock escalation".  By default, SQL Server uses (I think) row level locks for the delete.  However if an expression has more than some threshold -- 5,000 locks -- then SQL Server escalates the locking to the entire table.

This is an automatic mechanism, which you can turn off if you need.

There is a lot of information about this, both in SQL Server documents and related documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know that i delete too much data during a transaction,they make too much row locks,  The amount of row locks consume over the  40% memory  on my database.As a result, the lock escalation happend.Finally , I can't do any operation on the table. Thanks again!!